# C2081 'PLAYER': name in formal parameter list illegal - compiling using VS

Tags: c, windows, sdl

While trying to compile my C translation units player.c and game.c I am encountering two errors that I do not understand.

C2081   'PLAYER': name in formal parameter list illegal        game.h
C2371   'PLAYER': redefinition; different basic types          player.h

game.c

```
#include "game.h"
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool game_init(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer, const char* window_title, int window_width, int window_height)
{
    bool success = true;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1"))
        {
            printf("Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!\n");
        }

        window = SDL_CreateWindow(window_title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
            if (renderer == NULL)
            {
                printf("Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0); // default black background

                int img_flags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                if (!(IMG_Init(img_flags) & img_flags))
                {
                    printf("SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s", IMG_GetError());
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void game_start(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    PLAYER* player = NULL;
    player_init(player, renderer);
}

void game_process_input(bool* game_is_running)
{
    SDL_Event e;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
    {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            *game_is_running = false;
        }
    }
}

void game_update(GAME* game_state, PLAYER* player, float delta_time, int window_width, int window_height)
{
    if (game_state->state == MENU)
    {
        //scene_load_menu();
    }
    if (game_state->state == STARTED)
    {
        player_update(game_state, player, delta_time, window_width, window_height);
        //enemy_update();
    }
    else if (game_state->state == PLAYER_WIN)
    {
        //scene_player_wins();
    }
    else
    {
        //scene_player_lost();
    }
}

void game_render(GAME* game_state, PLAYER* player, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    //scene_render();
    player_render(renderer, game_state, player);
    //enemy_render();

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void game_cleanup(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    renderer = NULL;

    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "player.h"

typedef enum State
{
    MENU = 0,
    STARTED,
    PLAYER_LOST,
    PLAYER_WIN
} STATE;

typedef struct Game
{
    STATE state;
} GAME;

bool game_init(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer, const char* window_title, int window_width, int window_height);

void game_start(SDL_Renderer* renderer);

void game_process_input(bool* game_is_running);

void game_update(GAME* game_state, PLAYER* player, float delta_time, int window_width, int window_height);

void game_render(GAME* game_state, PLAYER* player, SDL_Renderer* renderer);

void game_cleanup(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer);

#endif
```

player.c

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "player.h"
#include "texture.h"

bool player_init(PLAYER* player, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
   player->health = 5;
   player->width = 20;
   player->height = 20;
   player->position_x = 400;
   player->position_y = 300;
   player->velocity = 100;
   
   if (!texture_load_from_file(renderer, player->texture, "Assets/PlayerShip.png"))
   {
      return false;
   }
   
   return true;
}

void player_input(PLAYER* player, float delta_time, int window_width, int window_height)
{
   player->position_x += player->velocity * delta_time;

   if (player->position_x < 0)
   {
      player->position_x = 0;
   }
   else if (player->position_x > window_width - player->width)
   {
      player->position_x = window_width - player->width;
   }

   player->position_y += player->velocity * delta_time;

   if (player->position_y < 0)
   {
      player->position_y = 0;
   }
   else if (player->position_y > window_height - player->height)
   {
      player->position_y = window_height - player->height;
   }
}

void player_update(const GAME* game_state, PLAYER* player, float delta_time, int window_width, int window_height)
{
   if (game_state->state == STARTED)
   {
      player_input(player, delta_time, window_width, window_height);
   }
}

void player_render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, const GAME* game_state, PLAYER* player)
{
   if (SDL_QueryTexture(player->texture, NULL, NULL, &player->width, &player->height) == 0)
   {
      SDL_Rect renderQuad = { player->position_x, player->position_y, player->width, player->height };
      SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, player->texture, NULL, &renderQuad);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Cannot get player texture dimensions!\n SDL_Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
   }
}
```

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "game.h"

typedef struct Player
{
   SDL_Texture* texture;
   int width;
   int height;
   float velocity;
   int position_x;
   int position_y;
   int health;
} PLAYER;

bool player_init(PLAYER* player, SDL_Renderer* renderer);

void player_input(PLAYER* player, float delta_time, int window_width, int window_height);

void player_update(const GAME* game_state, PLAYER* player, float delta_time, int window_width, int window_height);

void player_render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, const GAME* game_state, PLAYER* player);

#endif
```

I am compiling on Windows using Visual Studio Community 2022 17.9

I have tried to ensure that the header files have header guards and only include what they need, the same applied to the .c files.

I verified I only define the PLAYER struct once.

I tried changing the C version compiled with by the VS compiler from C11 to C17 and vica versa.

Can someone explain why these errors occur?

Comment: You have circular includes. Player includes Game and Game includes Player. You should be able to fix this with a forward declaration of `GAME` in player.h and removing the include. You could also forward declare `PLAYER` in game.h.

Comment: Thank you, I have moved all struct declarations in one header file, instead of multiple ones and that solved the issue!